# Configure Maven or Nexus to link trunk artifact at static URL

Tags: maven, nexus

My current Jenkins deployment job retrieves war file generated from maven build process from Nexus repository.  The deployment is done this way since I can not use hot deployment for my environments.  Currently I used parameterized build with Jenkins so I can manually enter the version number for my artifact.  Is there a way to configure Maven or Nexus so the artifact generate from the latest trunk build can be accessed from an static URL?  For example:

```
http://mynexus:8081/nexus/content/repository/snapshots/com/somepackage/my-app/trunk/my-app-trunk.war
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a way to do this in Nexus. But you can access the latest successful build from Jenkins, with a URL like this: `http://localhost:8080/jenkins/job/jobname/lastSuccessfulBuild/my-app-trunk.war`

You have to enable artifact archiving for your war file, then you can access it.

Comment: Thanks that might be the way to go.  Nexus is a repository for Maven.

Comment: *You have to enable artifact archiving for your war file, then you can access it* <- this is what I missed. I now configured this as post-build action and finally I see and can download the artifact. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here, we discovered about :

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Maven+Deployment+Linker

Which does the job.

Hope that helps.